# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError / ClassNotFoundException

Tags: exception, servlets, birt

I'm trying to run BIRT Servlet example:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/07/26/deploying-birt.html?page=2

I think I added all required jars to buildpath of my project but I can't make this thing run for days now.

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class WebReport
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/IRenderOption
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anything else I forgot to do?
Can you please help me understand this error and running the servlet? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the JAR file containing the class `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption` is present inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: It's in org.eclipse.birt.report.engine_3.7.2.v20120213.jar and I added it to buildpath. Do I have to copy it to mentioned folder?

Comment: Did you create a `Dynamic Web Project` or an ordinary `Java Project`?

Comment: I created Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: Meanwhile, I added all jars to lib folder instead of buildpath and now I get 404 - The requested resource (/WebReport/) is not available.

Comment: Well, what is your project named?

Comment: Can you maybe try importing this project yourself?
[Download project](http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/07/26/examples/birtdeployment.zip)

Comment: It seems that the problem was in path of some configuration file which I wanted to load. Thanks for your help anyway!!